# ContainerRequestFilter url pattern filter

Tags: jersey

How to apply my custom implementation for the ContainerRequestFilter to certain URL pattern, just like the Web Filters, where can I set the url-pattern for that kind of filter?

Comment: If your resource paths are properly set, this could be achieved implicitly with [name binding](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9882). This is the only declarative way I can think of. Otherwise, you can do it programmatically inside the filter. Any other way I can think of is much less trivial